# Slider that increased center slide width. (Slider plugin suggestions)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I wanted to create slider when it slide center slide width must have incresed and the two slide next to it stay on normal slide.

I have tried one using [slick](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) slider.

Here is the code pen [link](https://codepen.io/sameeraliyanage/pen/ejLqpB) that I have tried.

But this is not smooth and slide next to center slide not showing properly.

If anyone know some better slider for do exact kind of this please suggest me a link.

```js
$('.slider').slick({
  slidesToShow: 3,
  centerMode: true,
  centerPadding: "0px",
  speed: 1000
  
});

$('.slider').on('beforeChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide){

  $(slick).next().css({
    'margin-left':'auto'
  });//this code not working
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  background: #102131;
}
.slider {
  width: 1140px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
  color: white;
}
.slider .slide {
  padding: 0px;
}
.slider .slide .child-element {
  transition: all .2s ease;
  background: #0c1c79;
  width: 100%;
  height: 800px;
  width: 300px;
}
.slider .slide .child-element .imgWrap img {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}
.slider .slide .child-element .desc {
  display: none;
}
.slider .slide.slick-active:last-chid .child-element {
  margin-left: auto;
}
.slider .slide.slick-center .child-element {
  background: rebeccapurple;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-70px, 0px);
          transform: translate(-70px, 0px);
  width: calc(100% + 140px);
  max-width: initial;
}
.slider .slide.slick-center .child-element .desc {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.5.0/slick.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.5.0/slick-theme.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.5.0/slick.min.js"></script>
<div class="slider">
  <div class="slide">
    <div class="child-element">
       <div class="imgWrap">
         <img  src="https://www.scopecinemas.com/images/movie/dark900x12001.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="text">Title1</div>
      <div class="desc">Lorem ipsum dolor</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <div class="child-element">
       <div class="imgWrap">
         <img  src="https://www.scopecinemas.com/images/movie/trans900x1200.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="text">Title2</div>
      <div class="desc">Lorem ipsum dolor</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <div class="child-element">
       <div class="imgWrap">
         <img  src="https://www.scopecinemas.com/images/movie/mi900x1200.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="text">Title3</div>
      <div class="desc">Lorem ipsum dolor</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <div class="child-element">
       <div class="imgWrap">
         <img  src="https://www.scopecinemas.com/images/movie/Venom900x1200.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="text">Title4</div>
      <div class="desc">Lorem ipsum dolor</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <div class="child-element">
       <div class="imgWrap">
         <img  src="https://www.scopecinemas.com/images/movie/alpha900x1200.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="text">Title5</div>
      <div class="desc">Lorem ipsum dolor</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```